# How easy it is for MoS2 to become oxidized

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, oxidation-state

I made I high pressurized $\ce{MoS2}$ pellet, using a 6 ton pressurizer. I used very thin powder to create the pellet.

I am using this pellet on beam, with some nuclear techniques. In my spectra I can see oxygen.

How easy it is for $\ce{MoS2}$ to become oxidized?

Comment: I think you have to use XPS to determine if the Oxygen is from adsorption or oxidation.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the problem has been examined even 50 years ago, probably in order to determine if/how oxidation would alter the the properties of $\ce{MoS2}$ as a lubricant.

[Here](https://archive.org/details/nasa_techdoc_19930082560) is an old NASA document from 1949, and in [Surface Oxidation of Molybdenum Disulfide](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/j150531a020) from 1955, the authors state in the abstract, that the oxidation is limited to the outmost surface layer, which then passivates and protects the rest of the batch.

Answer (score 3):

Just as for almost every compound of d-elements, $MoS_2$ tends to adsorb molecules from gases on its surface. This is especially true for fine powders, that have high surface-per-gram. MoS2 is especially troublesome, because in strongly reductive atmosphere it is reduced to metallic molybdenum. So, ideally, to get a pure MoS2 you have to

- threat powder with $H_2S$ at about 300-400 Celsium before use
- press powder into pellet under argon
- not allow it to touch air for any significant amount of time (more that several seconds)

In general a very brief exposure to air may significantly oxidize $MoS_2$ catalysts, so you can safely assume that if your $MoS_2$ touched air, it contains oxygen, especially if it is in fine powder.